# How do I write my wrapper class to use partial generic type inference?

Tags: c#, generics, f#, type-inference, fluent-interface

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893698/partial-generic-type-inference-possible-in-c).

I'd like to create a generic wrapper class:

```
public abstract class Wrapper<T>
{
    internal protected T Wrapped { get; set; }
}
```

With the following extensions:

```
public static class WrapperExtensions
{
    public static W Wrap<W,T>(this T wrapped) where W:Wrapper<T>,new()
    {
        return new W {Wrapped = wrapped};
    }

    public static T Unwrap<T>(this Wrapper<T> w)
    {
        return w.Wrapped;
    }
}
```

Now assume a concrete Wrapper:

```
public class MyIntWrapper : Wrapper<int>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am wrapping an integer with value " + Wrapped;
    }
}
```

I would like to call the `Wrap` extension like this:

```
MyIntWrapper wrapped = 42.Wrap<MyIntWrapper>();
```

This is not possible because in c# we need to provide both type arguments to the `Wrap` extension.
(it's all or nothing)

Apparently partial inference is possible in F#.

How would the above code look in F#?

Would it be possible to use it from C#?

Comment: Why don't you just define an implicit conversion? You can than write `MyIntWrapper wrapped = 42;`

Comment: Why do you have multiple wrapper classes?  Just use a single wrapper.  Also, as said, implicit conversions are great with wrapper classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Apparently partial inference is possible in F#.*

Yes, only W would need to be specified in your example. T will be inferred.

*How would the above code look in F#?*

```ml
[<AbstractClass>]
type Wrapper<'a>() =
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable internal Wrapped : 'a

let Wrap<'W,'T when 'W :> Wrapper<'T> and 'W: (new: unit -> 'W)> (wrapped: 'T): 'W = 
    let instance = new 'W()
    instance.Wrapped <- wrapped
    instance

let Unwrap (w: Wrapper<_>) = w.Wrapped

type MyIntWrapper() =
    inherit Wrapper<int>()
    override this.ToString() = 
        sprintf "I'm wrapping an integer with value %d" this.Wrapped
```

And you can call Wrap from F# interactive this way

```
> let wrapped = Wrap<MyIntWrapper,_> 5;;
val wrapped : MyIntWrapper = I'm wrapping an integer with value 5
```

In my opinion this is not very idiomatic in F#, I would rather use Discriminated Unions and Pattern Matching for wrapping/unwrapping but I don't know exactly what's your specific case.

*Would it be possible to use it from C#?*

Sure, but if you call `Wrap` from C# you're back to C# type inference and will have to specify the second type parameter.

Comment: Thanks, spot-on answer to the question, unfortunately not with the outcome I had hoped for.

Answer (score 3):

Implement custom implicit conversion:

[MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
struct MyIntWrapper
{
    public MyIntWrapper(int value) 
    {
        this.value = value; 
    }

    static public implicit operator MyIntWrapper(int value)
    {
        return new MyIntWrapper(value);
    }

    static public explicit operator int(MyIntWrapper wrapper)
    {
         return wrapper.value;
    }

    private int value;
}
```

You can then write:

```
MyIntWrapper wrapped = 42;
```

Comment: Why do you insist on it being generic?

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I'm looking for.
_I'd like to create a_ **generic** _wrapper class_.
Your answer is just another kind of syntactic sugar for `MyIntWrapper`, but not for any other class derived from `Wrapper<T>`.
You could as well write a non-generic `Wrap` extension for `MyIntWrapper` with almost the same effect.

Comment: _Why do you insist on it being generic?_ 

Avoid writing boiler-plate wrapper code

Comment: @3D-Grabber Why do you have multiple generic wrappers?  Why not just one single wrapper class (non-abstract) that can wrap anything?  The reason he's defining this behavior multiple times is a direct result of you defining multiple wrapper classes.  For the record though, the conversion *to* the wrapper needs to be in the derived class, but the conversion *from* the wrapper can be in the abstract class

Comment: @Servy: Wrapper aka Adapter Pattern. I need different adapters for different purposes (e.g. different ViewModels in MVVM), hence the need for subclassing. Let me know if you have a better solution for those szenarios

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in F#:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

type Wrapper<'T> =
  abstract Wrapped : 'T

[<Extension>]
module WrapperExtensions =

  [<Extension>]
  let Wrap wrapped = { new Wrapper<_> with member x.Wrapped = wrapped }

  [<Extension>]
  let Unwrap (w: Wrapper<_>) = w.Wrapped
```

And then use it from C# like this:

```
var wrapped = 42.Wrap();
wrapped.Unwrap();
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a helper class to allow you to separate the generic parmeters into two separate calls, allowing you to infer the one you want.  LinqPad sample:

```
void Main()
{
    MyIntWrapper wrapped = 42.Wrap().To<MyIntWrapper>(); 
}

public abstract class Wrapper<T>
{
    internal protected T Wrapped { get; set; }
}

public static class WrapperExtensions
{
    public static WrapHelper<T> Wrap<T>(this T wrapped) 
    {
        return new WrapHelper<T>(wrapped);
    }

    public static T Unwrap<T>(this Wrapper<T> w)
    {
        return w.Wrapped;
    }

    public class WrapHelper<T> 
    {
        private T wrapped;

        public WrapHelper(T wrapped) 
        {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        public W To<W>() where W : Wrapper<T>, new() 
        {
            return new W {Wrapped = wrapped};
        }
    }
}

public class MyIntWrapper : Wrapper<int>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am wrapping an integer with value " + Wrapped;
    }
}
```

In particular, notice the new class `WrapHelper<T>`, which exposes the method `To<W>`.  To that method you pass in an explicit generic argument, but to the original `Wrap<T>` method, it's inferred by the `this T`, returning an instance of that helper class, allowing you to chain the method calls together to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I know that fluent interface separation trick :)
... just looking for a more syntactically terse solution

Comment: Terse for the caller or the implementer of your static wrapper methods?  Not sure why `5.Wrap().To<TWrapper>()` is considered wordy?

Comment: It's certainly a good solution. Problem with fluent interfaces is that some people (consumers of the API) are not used to it and find it confusing ("Wrap<T> is returning a WrapHelper?, what am I supposed to do with that?"). I tried this sort of solution before. Also, I'm sort of a perfectionist...

Comment: @KirkWoll Well, when you compare it to a solution involving implicit conversions that requires *no* code for the caller...

Comment: @Servy, in an invented (or other) language?  I was trying to provide an ideal C# solution.

Comment: @KirkWoll C# has user defined implicit conversions...why isn't that part of the ideal solution?

Comment: @Servy, how do you propose to make that work?  If you have a suggestion, by all means propose an answer.

Comment: @KirkWoll There is already an answer to this question that does what I've described; in fact it's the most highly upvoted answer to this question (and always has been).

Comment: +1 The solution above is not generic and thus requires a class to be written for every type to be used, so it is likely not acceptable since the asker wanted a generic solution.  This is the best way to do it and I do not consider Fluent interfaces to be a difficult concept, especially with Intellisense where you can hit the period key and see the methods available to call.  Further, you can mark the method returning the helper class with the PureAttribute and Resharper will give you a warning if you don't use the returned helper.