# Set a constraint for generic type, that T inherits from another generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to create a generic class, but one of the where conditions for the type is, that it must extend a specific class which unfortunately is a generic class, too.

Let me explain, say we already have this abstract base class (and can't change them, because it is part of a third party framework):

```
public abstract class SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx> : IDisposable
    where Tx : class
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And there are several decendants of this base class, that implement it with concrete types, like this:

```
public class SomeConcreteClass : SomeGenericBaseClass<string>
{}
```

I want to create a class, that can wrap those descendants of `SomeGenericBaseClass`:

```
public class MyClass<Ta> : IDisposable
    // some magig where condition, that makes sure, Ta is a descendent of  SomeGenericBaseClass
{
    private Ta wrappedObject;

    public MyClass(Ta objectToWrap)
    {
        this.wrappedObject = objectToWrap;
    }

    public DoSomething()
    {
        this.wrappedObject.SomeProperty = "If I want to use this property, I have to make sure, that Ta/wrappedObject is a descendant of SomeGenericBaseClass, which declares SomeProperty.";
    }
}
```

How do I do this, without the where condition being something like

```
public class MyClass<Ta, Tb> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb>, new()
    where Tb : class
```

which would mean that I have to pass two types, every time I use `MyClass`

```
var obj = new MyClass<SomeConcreteClass, string>();
```

although Ta=`SomeConcreteClass` allows only one valid type for Tb (`string`) ...

Comment: I don't think there is! You can't constrain an open generic with another open generic..... it just doesn't make logical sense. I think you may not need generics in the first place - have you considered all alternatives?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to constrain it to an open Type.  You might be able to do something with a "helper" Interface applied to the base type that you constrain it to.  Simmilar to what it happening [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25309360/526724).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Answer (score 1):

## Second update

In your updated question, you've provided us with a more concrete usage, where `Ta` = `SomeConcreteClass` and `Tb` = `string`.

Here's an updated snippet to show how my answer should be used:

```
public class SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx> : IDisposable
    where Tx : class { }

public class MyClass<Ta> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<string>, new()

var obj = new MyClass<SomeConcreteClass>();
```

If this is still not exactly what you want, then you are not explaining it clearly enough (unless someone else manages to answer it. We're talking about a very intricate setup, which means that there are **many** possibilities here, but their validity hinges on your specific requirements.

My last example here assumes that **every** `MyClass<Ta>` object will have a `Ta` which is a  `SomeGenericBaseClass<string>`.

If, however, `MyClass<ASecondConcreteClass>` would be a `SomeGenericBaseClass<int>` and that is correct according to your requirement, then I again refer to bullet point 3: if the `Tb` is specific to which `Ta` is being used, then you obviously have to mention both of them (since it is not implicitly clear which `Tb` belongs to which `Ta`).

---

---

## Update, as per your update

> Whoops, I made a typo, when typing the classes into SO. Tx / Tb should only have a class constraint. I edited the question.

```
public class SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx> : IDisposable
    where Tx : class { }

public class MyClass<Ta> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb>, new()
```

If this is the correct case, then there's no reason to mention `where Tb : class`, because this is already inherently the case because of the already defined `where Tx : class`

Therefore, you can simply omit the requirement as it is redundant:

```
public class MyClass<Ta, Tb> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb>, new()
```

The compiler will inherently require `Tb` to fulfill the requirements of `where Tx : class`.

---

---

## The old answer

### Your setup is logically inconsistent.

First, you set up your classes like so:

```
public class SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx> : IDisposable
    where Tx : class { }
```

Here, `SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx>` is `IDisposable`, but `Tx` is nothing more than a class.

But later on, you expect something different:

```
public class MyClass<Ta> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb>, new()
    where Tb : IDisposable
```

But here, you expect `Tb` (which is your `Tx` from the earlier example) **itself** to be `IDisposable`.

Your requirements have shifted. And I'm not sure whether this is by mistake or by intention. I see three options here:

### 1. `Tx`/`Tb` is always required to be `IDisposable`

This seems to make the most sense, based on my assumption of what you are trying to achieve.

```
public class SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx>
    where Tx : class, IDisposable { }

public class MyClass<Ta> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb>, new()
```

This forgoes the need for `MyClass<Ta>` to require anything about `Tb` (it only needs to mention the type itself of course), because your requirements are already part of the `SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx>` definition.

*Note: You can also still have `SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx>` be `IDisposable` too. There's nothing wrong with that; but I've omitted it from my example to prove that it isn't **necessary**.*

### 2. `Tx`/`Tb` is never required to be `IDisposable`

If this is the case, then you've probably gotten confused between `Tx` and `SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx>`, but in fact only the latter needs to be `IDisposable`.

```
public class SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx> : IDisposable
    where Tx : class { }

public class MyClass<Ta> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb>, new()
```

### 3. `Tb` is sometimes required to be `IDisposable`. It should be `IDisposable` for `MyClass<Ta>`, but not for the base implementation of `SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb/Tx>`

Notice that in **both** previous cases cases, I've omitted any type requirements for `Tb` in the class definition of `MyClass<Ta>`. This is because in both cases, the type requirements were global. Every instance of `SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx>` would then behave the same way across your entire application.

It's not impossible that you want to add this requirement **only** for `MyClass<Ta>`.

But if this is what you want, then you cannot avoid having to mention `Tb` in your `MyClass<Ta>` definition. If the type requirement only fits in the scope of `MyClass<Ta>`, then that is where you'll have to put it (and having to mention the type is then an obvious consequence).

```
public class SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx> : IDisposable
    where Tx : class { }

public class MyClass<Ta, Tb> : IDisposable
    where Ta : SomeGenericBaseClass<Tb>, new()
    where Tb : IDisposable
```

Notice that in this case, `SomeGenericBaseClass<Tx>` is **always** required to be `IDisposable`, but `Tx` itself is required to be `IDisposable` **only for `MyClass<A>`**.

*However, I think this design, while possible, isn't a good approach. At least, that is my opinion because I can't think of a valid use case for this setup. I'd be interested in hearing why you'd want to use it this way, if this is the case.*

---

Comment: Whoops, I made a typo, when typing the classes into SO.  Tx / Tb should only have a class constraint. I edited the question.

Comment: But the code in 2. doesn't work, `Tb` isn't recognized, when it is not declared...

Comment: @Hinek: `Tb` must only be declared (in the `MyClass<Ta>` definition) if it is used as a generic type parameter **for `MyClass<Ta>`**. As a similar example, I can declare a class like so: `class MyIntList : List<int>` without requiring `MyIntList` to have a generic parameter.

Comment: When I do this, I get the error "The type 'Tb' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'Tx'", so it seems not to work implicit.

Comment: @Hinek: that means you are literally using `Tb`, and that is not just an example? You should be using a concrete class there, e.g. `SomeGenericBaseClass<myFooClass>`. Otherwise, I refer back to my answer in 3., if you're using a generic type parameter then you must obviously define the generic type parameters that you are using.

Comment: @Hinek: Based on your last comment, you seem to be confusing the generic type parameter (e.g. `T` in `IEnumerable<T>`) with supplying a concrete class (e.g `String` in `IEnumerable<String>`, which is the **implementation** of a generically typed `IEnumerable<T>`). To avoid confusion, you should maybe post your **concrete** examples, because your use of simplified example types makes it impossible to distinguish between whether you're using actual type parameters or implementations of previously defined generic classes.

Comment: @Hinek: Please see my updated answer. This will probably be my last update, as we keep circling back to the same point every time: logical consistency in class definitions. I have explained the source of your issue as best as I can, but if you're asking me for a specific implementation, then my answer can only be as accurate as your description, and that is not clear right now. You're using a very intricate setup here, which of course requires an intricate understanding of what you actually need. If you have a direct question, feel free to ask it (in another question).