# Constrain Generic Parameter to ICollection with Varying Element Types

Tags: c#, generics, collections, type-inference

## Generic Collection Problem

This resembles a `Tuple<?,?>` problem. A utility class needs to invoke a collection of processors; processors expose a generic method, `Process<TInput, TOutput>`. The utility class should expose a method that accepts a collection of processors and the input to the first processor, then iterates through the processors, invoking something like `y = Process(x)`, where `x` is the output of the previous iteration.

This can probably be achieved through boxing (e.g., changing my example below to use `<object,object>` as the type arguments), but ideally the solution would enforce a constraint that each processor's input type matches the previous processor's output type, which requires type discovery within each iteration.

## Example:

```csharp
public interface IProcessor
{
    TOutput Process<TInput, TOutput>(object firstInput);
}
public interface ISequencer<in TCollection, in TFirstInput, out TLastOutput> where TCollection : ICollection<IProcessor>
{
    public TLastOutput ProcessRange(TCollection collection, TFirstInput firstInput)
    {
        if (collection == null || collection.Count < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(collection),
                @"A minimum of 2 collection members is required.");
        }
        // Goal: discover the type of "?" output at runtime:
        var x = collection.First().Process<TFirstInput,?>(firstInput);
        object y;
        foreach (var processor in collection.Skip(1).Take(collection.Count - 1))
        {
            // Goal: replace <?,?> without boxing:
            y = processor.Process<?,?>(x);
            x = y;
        }
        // Goal: discover the type of "?" input at runtime:
        y = collection.Last().Process<?,TLastOutput>(x);
        // this cast would be unnecessary if one could discover the generic type
        // of each collection member at runtime:
        return (TLastOutput)y;
    }
}
```

I can't help but think there must be a cleaner way to do this than boxing. The ideal solution would discover the `TInput` and `TOutput` of `IProcessor` within each iteration. Perhaps Marc Gravell's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16479852/141508 applies, but I can't figure out how the `YourParent` parameter / property in his example fits into the solution.

Comment: And what is the *real* source of the `TInput` and `TOutput`? Can you show the example implementation of the `IProcessor` or add more details about the type system? I mean, for the current interface declaration, the types should be given by the caller. And the caller at the same time wants to discover the types ... where it want to discover them from? Looks like chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @serg A more concrete example: let's say we have three processors. Processor1 accepts a string and returns a string. Processor2 accepts a string and returns a Bitmap. Processor3 accepts an array of integers and returns an integer. Client wants a utility that can iterate through a set of processors, discover the type arguments, and chain input->output->input. The type of the first input and the last output would be known at compile time, but the intervening collection members' type parameters would only be known at runtime.

Comment: You are saying "collection members' type parameters would only be known at runtime". So, from what source will it be known? Literally, let's say we get  the `IProcessor` instance from the collection. Where should we look to know the `TInput & TOoutput`? This is not a technical/implementation question, it's an architectural one.

Comment: @Serg - the type would be stored as metadata in a database row containing externally-accessible properties of the processor. It would be exposed as a pair of properties, `Type InputType { get; }` and `Type OutputType { get; }`.

Comment: then I would just like to see the example of the `IPorcessor` implementation even more, because I don't understand what kind of type safety you expect to achieve, since the the `IPorcessor` implementation is non-type-safe by design. Let's take the simplest one, the int->string processor. And how should it handle the `Process<DateTime, double>("some string")` call (where we totally messed up all the types, but which is perfectly good from the compiler's point of view)?

Comment: I mean, in the current architecture you can just work with `objects` and nothing gets lost. If the `IPorcessor` will be type-safe (i.e., becomes `IProcessor<TIn, TOut>`), then it will be possible to build a type-safe piplene as per @Servy answer or with other approach if you really need the collection and not a chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your first problem is that your processors, as per their interface, all *claim* that they can accept inputs of any type and provide outputs of any type, even though that's clearly not true for your actual processors.  Instead of a generic method, thus allowing the caller of the method to supply the input and output types each time they call `Process` on *any* processor, you need the generic arguments to be on the interface, so any particular implementation accepts one type of input and provides one type of output.

```
public interface IProcessor<in TInput, out TOutput>
{
    TOutput Process(TInput firstInput);
}
```

Next, putting a number of processors, all designed to create a pipeline where the output of one is used as the input of the next, into an `ICollection` that maintains static typing is inherently doomed.  Such a collection would need to have a generic argument for not only the input and output types, but every single intermediate type, and since generic arguments are a statically defined finite list, you'd need to create a new collection for every single *number of items in that collection* which isn't really feasible unless you only ever have a very small number of items, and even then, working with such a type would be horrendous.

Fortunately, given what your final interface needs to do, there's no actually need to put them in a collection.  Simply write a single method to link two processors together, such that a new processor is created that passes the input to the first processor, then the result of that to the second, and finally returns that result.

```
public static class Processor
{
    public static IProcessor<TInput, TOutput> Link<TInput, TIntermediate, TOutput>(
        this IProcessor<TInput, TIntermediate> first, IProcessor<TIntermediate, TOutput> second)
    {
        return new LinkedProcessor<TInput, TIntermediate, TOutput>(first, second);
    }
    private class LinkedProcessor<TInput, TIntermediate, TOutput> : IProcessor<TInput, TOutput>
    {
        private IProcessor<TInput, TIntermediate> first;
        private IProcessor<TIntermediate, TOutput> second;
        public LinkedProcessor(IProcessor<TInput, TIntermediate> first, IProcessor<TIntermediate, TOutput> second)
        {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
        public TOutput Process(TInput firstInput)
        {
            return second.Process(first.Process(firstInput));
        }
    }
}
```

By then linking your various processors, one after the other (since a linked processor can itself be linked as either the input or output of another processor in a chain) you can create a pipeline of entirely statically typed processors.  And you don't even need a separate type for the `ISequencer` at all, you can simply have an `IProcessor` who's process method processes all of the linked values in its own implementation.

```
//Note: each Processor is a stand in for a specific IProcessor doing actual work
IProcessor<int, DateTime> pipeline = new Processor<int, double>()
    .Link(new Processor<double, string>())
    .Link(new Processor<string, DateTime>());
DateTime result = pipeline.Process(5);
```

And all of this maintains static typing.  If you try to link a processor whose input doesn't match the other processor's output, it won't compile.

As a purely academic concern, it's worth noting that such a pipeline is conceptually a binary tree, which from a computer science perspective, *is* a collection, but you couldn't meaningfully put the processors in an `Collection<T>` since currently each "node" only knows of the types of itself and, if it has any, it's children.  There is no one type that knows of the types of every single one at the same time.