# Can a C# extension infer a generic type?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I've been doing some searching and been confused with the answers that I find. Pardon my lack of tech jargon.

I'm writing an extension for Mvc.

```
public static MvcHtmlString FormTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>( this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var attr = expression.GetAttribute<TModel, TProperty, HtmlPropertyAttribute>();

    return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { placeholder = attr.Value });
}

public static T GetAttribute<TModel, TProperty, T>(this Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
            where T : Attribute
        {
            var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression");

            return memberExpression.Member.GetAttribute<T>();
        }
```

What I'm wondering is if I can shortcut passing TModel and TProperty into my second extension because the parameter is already contains that information.

Essentially I want to turn this

```
expression.GetAttribute<TModel, TProperty, HtmlPropertyAttribute>();
```

into this

```
expression.GetAttribute<HtmlPropertyAttribute>();
```

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/partial-type-inference-in-net.html

Comment: This is a dupe of something... will look.

Comment: Is there any particular reason `TModel` and `TProperty` need to be type parameters of the second method? Why not remove them and change the type of `expression` to `LambdaExpression`?

Comment: @JonSkeet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2893698/34397

Comment: @SLaks: Found another one... just fighting a flaky connection.

Comment: @SLaks In a non related issue - do you have an RSS to your blog?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: http://blog.slaks.net/feeds/posts/default.xml

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. +1