# Avoid to specify type in Generics with extension method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

This is a design question,
I have this extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<R> ToViewModels<T,R>(this IQueryable<T> DBModels_Q)
{
    //calling another method (irrilevant for this question)
    return ToViewModels<T, R>().Invoke(DBModels_Q.AsExpandable());
}
```

This method works really well if called with:

```
//db is the EntityFramework context and Employee is the DB table
db.Employee.ToViewModels<DBModels.Employee, ViewModels.Employee>();
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to use it without specifying the type of T:

```
db.Employee.ToViewModels<ViewModels.Employee>();
```

something like [How do I get the calling method name and type using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type-using-reflection) would be usefull.

**UPDATE**

like suggested the answer was at [Partial generic type inference possible in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893698/partial-generic-type-inference-possible-in-c)

sadly the only way is to wrap everything and use 2 methods:

```
public static ViewModelsWrapper<TSource> LoadViewModels<TSource> (this IQueryable<TSource> DBModels_Q)
    {
        return new ViewModelsWrapper<TSource>(DBModels_Q);
    }

    public class ViewModelsWrapper<TSource>
    {
        private readonly IQueryable<TSource> DBModels_Q;
        public ViewModelsWrapper(IQueryable<TSource> DBModels_Q)
        {
            this.DBModels_Q = DBModels_Q;
        }
        public IQueryable<TResult> GetViewModels<TResult>()
        {
            return ToModels<TSource, TResult>().Invoke(this.DBModels_Q.AsExpandable());
        }
    }
```

using it like

```
sv.db.Employee.LoadViewModels().GetViewModels<EmployeeModel>();
```

Comment: You exposed `ToViewModels` method but you call `ToModels`. Are they the same ?

Comment: No. There is no way that the compiler could desume the `R` type without looking inside the method body.

Comment: Is your update actually an answer? If so, please move it to one.

Comment: Actually I can't see the buttons to confirm the answer... the correct answer would be the one already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893698/partial-generic-type-inference-possible-in-c