# Equivalent of Linq's Any() function for when a collection has multiple items

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

In C#, using Linq, if I want to check if a collection has any elements, I can do this:

```
someCollection.Any()
```

which is preferable over

```
someCollection.Count() > 0
```

since the latter will count all the items in the collection, when I don't really care how many items there are, I just want to know if there are any.

Is there an equivalent for checking if a collection has more than one item? Something like:

```
someCollection.Many()
```

instead of having to do

```
someCollection.Count() > 1
```

Silly question, I know, and from my research, it doesn't look like there is. But since it's something I use frequently, I thought I'd double check with the community.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, .Count() > 1 is the way to do that.

Comment: I'd use `source.Take(2).Count() == 2` - that way it won't iterate over all of `source`.

Comment: @CetinBasoz `.Count()` will iterate over _all_ of the source `IEnumerable<T>`, which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: You can also do source.Skip(1).Any()

Comment: @Dai, but other ways suggested, are they really worth enough to use? I didn't benchmark any of them, but at least, a solution using Skip would be worse I think. Anyway, we don't even know what that someCollection is, depending on what that is checking the item at position 2 might be a simple and efficient way. If an array, length would be an answer already.

Comment: @CetinBasoz That's why my answer checks for `IReadOnlyCollection<T>.Count` and `ICollection<T>.Count` first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment:

First, you should check to see if `IEnumerable<T> source` *actually is* an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `ICollection<T>` because that has a `.Count` property you can use - which would be preferable to any iteration.

Assuming your `IEnumerable<T>` does not have an `O(1)` `.Count` property, if you want to see if there's *at least* 1 element (i.e. "*at least 2 or more*") then use `source.Take(2).Count() == 2` or `source.Skip(1).Any()`.

Like so:

```cs
public static Boolean Many<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source )
{
    if( source is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if( source is ICollection<T> col ) return col.Count >= 2;
    else if( source is IReadOnlyCollection<T> roCol ) return roCol.Count >= 2;

    return source.Take(2).Count() == 2;
}
```

---

If you want to be more efficient about it, do manual iteration:

```cs
public static Boolean Many<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source )
{
    if( source is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if( source is ICollection<T> col ) return col.Count >= 2;
    else if( source is IReadOnlyCollection<T> roCol ) return roCol.Count >= 2;

    Int32 count = 0;
    using( IEnumerator<T> iter = source.GetEnumerator() )
    {
        while( iter.MoveNext() && count < 2 )
        {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return count == 2;
}
```

---

If you want to be *even more* efficient about it, allow consumers to supply non-boxed enumerators (e.g. `List<T>.Enumerator`):

```cs
public static Boolean Many<TEnumerable,TEnumerator,TElement>( /*this*/ TEnumerable source, Func<TEnumerable,TEnumerator> getEnumerator )
    where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TElement>
    where TEnumerator : IEnumerator<TElement>
{
    if( source        is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if( getEnumerator is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getEnumerator));
    
    //

    if     ( source is ICollection<TElement>           col ) return col  .Count >= 2;
    else if( source is IReadOnlyCollection<TElement> roCol ) return roCol.Count >= 2;

    Int32 count = 0;
    using( TEnumerator iter = getEnumerator( source ) )
    {
        while( iter.MoveNext() && count < 2 )
        {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return count == 2;
}
```

Used like so:

```cs
List<String> listOfStrings = new List<String>() { ... };

if( listOfStrings.Many</*TEnumerable:*/ List<String>, /*TEnumerator:*/ List<String>.Enumerator, /*TElement:*/ String >( l => l.GetEnumerator() ) )
{
    
}
```

- Yes, it's ugly... it's unfortunate, [but C# still doesn't support this level of generic type-inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893698/partial-generic-type-inference-possible-in-c) - nor does it support *partial generic parameter application*.
- The `list.GetEnumerator()` part is needed as it's the only way to pass a `struct`-based enumerator into generic code without boxing (at least, not without reflection).

Comment: Take a look at the [`TryGetNonEnumeratedCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.trygetnonenumeratedcount) LINQ operator ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3c21cc5a0a486d08b5a7a4fdc2e1c2f9b02dbc9f/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs#L95)).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks - I've updated my post. I verified the code works in Linqpad 7.

Comment: Yep, now it's OK. I noticed that it compiles also without the `where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TElement>` constraint.