How can I use generic to imply type from inherited class in C#?
I have an interface:
public interface IFeature<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

and class
public class SharepointFeature : IFeature<string>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

And I want to create a method to get the feature:
public T GetFeature<T, TValue>() where T : IFeature<TValue>
{
    // some logic
}

And usage:
public void Test()
{
    // This one is working
    var feature = GetFeature<SharepointFeature, string>();
    // Desired version
    var feature = GetFeature<SharepointFeature>(); // I want to only specify one generic argument
}

How can I change my GetFeature to imply TValue from T?

You can’t. Partially inferring generic arguments is not supported in C#.

What a shame. That would be so great.

There are some possible workarounds via splitting the generic arguments across several methods/classes. See e.g. the top rated answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893698/partial-generic-type-inference-possible-in-c#4106826
